# how to reference a super class's method with a decorator using babel and javascript es6 classes

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-2016

I have a decorator in a base class called `authenticatedOnly` which is a static class method, that I'd like to use in a subclass.  What's the correct way of calling it in a child class?  `@super.authenticatedOnly` or `@authenticatedOnly` doesn't seem to work.

```
class ListService extends BaseService {
    name = 'list'
    @authenticated
    async read(req, resource, params, config, callback) {
        try {
            const lists = await List.find({username: req.session.currentUser.username}).exec();
            return callback(null, lists);
        } catch (error) {
            callback(fumble.http.internalServerError(error), null);
        }

    }
}
```

I can import the baseclass static methods like so:

```
import BaseService from './BaseService'
const authenticated = BaseService.authenticated
```

But I'm wondering if there is amore concise way of doing it.

Comment: It's probably easier to just have a decorators module and import from there.

Comment: Have you tried `@BaseService.authenticated`? Decorators are not looked up as properties of the class.

Comment: well it works if I just import the base service authenticated method as noted above...